# Showing div tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I am using VS.Net 2008. I have created a Ajax web application in C#. In the webform1 i have 6 div tags. In each of the div tags i am showing a .acsx file. Here i am able to move betwwen each of the tabs created using DIV and Jquery. Now when i am in UserControl1.acsx and click a button control in the webform1, I have to go to the last DIV tab. i.e UserControl6.acsx should come to front.

Comment: Hard, if not impossible to answer without the code, always post!

Comment: Also, consider a jQuery UI widget, like an accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code hard to answer but maybe you are looking for something along the lines of

```
$("selectorForContainerOfThe6DIVs div:last").show()
```

Comment: And you might need a .hide() in there, too, for the DIV you are leaving.